# How can I increase the performance of the program?

Tags: performance, prolog

I write a Prolog program for solving cryptarithms  but the running time is not so low. How can I improve the running time without using any other libraries? Thank you!

```
validDigit(X) :- member(X,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
validStart(X) :- member(X,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
assign([H|[]]) :- validDigit(H).
assign([H|Tail]) :- validDigit(H), assign(Tail), all_different([H|Tail]).

findTail(List,H,T) :- append(H,[T],List).

convert([T],T) :- validDigit(T).
convert(List,Num) :- findTail(List,H,T), convert(H,HDigit), Num is (HDigit*10+T).

verbalArithmetic(WordList,[H1|Tail1],[H2|Tail2],Word3) :-
    validStart(H1), validStart(H2), assign(WordList),
    convert([H1|Tail1],Num1),convert([H2|Tail2],Num2), convert(Word3,Num3),
    Sum is Num1+Num2, Num3 = Sum.
```

Comment: Use [tag:clpfd]!

Comment: What are concrete cases you consider? And what is the meaning of your program?

Comment: How are you calling your program? Sample call?

Comment: I call the program  verbalArithmetic([S,E,N,D,M,O,R,Y],[S,E,N,D],[M,O,R,E],[M,O,N,E,Y]).

Comment: This is for the cryptarithm SEND+MORE=MONEY